# Opening a binary file handled by C++ std::ifstream in gem5 syscall emulation fails is_open check

Tags: gem5

I have [mnist.loader.hpp](https://github.com/ARM-software/ML-examples/blob/master/armnn-mnist/mnist_loader.hpp) header file that opens and reads [t10k-images-idx3-ubyte](https://github.com/ARM-software/ML-examples/blob/master/armnn-mnist/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte) and [t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte](https://github.com/ARM-software/ML-examples/blob/master/armnn-mnist/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte) binary files in a given path using `std::ifstream` as can be seen in  the snippet below:

```
std::string imagePath = dataDir + std::string("t10k-images-idx3-ubyte");
std::string labelPath = dataDir + std::string("t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte");

std::ifstream imageStream(imagePath, std::ios::binary);
std::ifstream labelStream(labelPath, std::ios::binary);
```

The path of the directory having those two binary files `dataDir` is embedded in [mnist_caffe.cpp](https://github.com/ARM-software/ML-examples/blob/master/armnn-mnist/mnist_caffe.cpp). It could be changed as per my setting in the `std::string dataDir = "data/"` line.

I set `dataDir` to  `/home/mohamed/`, then compiled and statically-linked an aarch64 executable out of them and my target is to simulate it on gem5.

### **The problem**:

gem5 always fails to read the files. It gives `"Failed to read /home/mohamed/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte"`.

If we have a look once again at [mnist_loader.hpp](https://github.com/ARM-software/ML-examples/blob/master/armnn-mnist/mnist_loader.hpp), we will notice that this error message is due to either the file not being open as or being opened but can't be read :

```
if (!imageStream.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load " << imagePath << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
```

or

```
imageStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&magic), sizeof(magic));
    if (magic != 0x03080000)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read " << imagePath << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
```

or

```
if (!imageStream.good())
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to read " << imagePath << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}
```

My guess is that gem5 can not open the file in the first place!

### **My trials:**

(I am only interested in opening and reading `t10k-images-idx3-ubyte` for now)

1- Trying to pass the file to the stdin using -i option: `$ ./build/ARM/gem5.opt ./configs/example/se.py -c mnist_caffe -i '/home/mohamed/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte'`

2- Using -o: `$ ./build/ARM/gem5.opt ./configs/example/se.py -c mnist_caffe  -o "-i /home/mohamed/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte"`

3- Using --redirects: `$ ./build/ARM/gem5.opt ./configs/example/se.py -c /home/mohamed/NNDeploy/ML-examples/armnn-mnist/mnist_caffe --redirects /home/mohamed/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte=/home/mohamed/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte`

4- Opening the binary file in the host system using `xxd` and then passing it to stdin: `$ ./build/ARM/gem5.opt ./configs/example/se.py -c ~/NNDeploy/ML-examples/armnn-mnist/mnist_caffe -o " -i /usr/bin/xxd /home/mohamed/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte"`

All the above resulted in the same failed-to-read message. I ran out of ideas and it would be great if someone could provide some suggestions!

Comment: Can you provide one minimal single-file C++ program that reproduces the problem? E.g. [this minimal example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/4e3f8be59ec060aa60572cd46b259ad67846b2d7/userland/cpp/file_write_read.cpp) works fine for me on gem5 3ca404da175a66e0b958165ad75eb5f54cb5e772 aarch64. Also try to `--debug-falgs SyscallBase` to narrow it down.

Comment: @CiroSantilli I will try to do that and get back to you